# location undefine when i try to convert latitude and longitude to an address format

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var location
var point = new google.maps.LatLng(data[key].latitude, data[key].longitude);
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({
  latLng: point
}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    if (results[0]) {
      location = results[0].formatted_address;
    }
  }
});

console.log(location);
```

when i console variable `location` is undefined outside of `geocode` function
here `location` is undefined.
inside `geocode` i am getting location value.

Comment: I recommend cleaning up your question if possible. If I am reading this right you're wondering why `location` is `undefined` in your console logs?

Comment: @Pixxl check now

Comment: Have you tried debugging the response first? Such as `console.log({status:status, results:results}` ... My first assumption is that one or both of your logic `if` statements are not evaluating to true.

Comment: @Pixxl when i console status and result i am getting  results: null
​
status: "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"

Comment: Okay so "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" would probably not be a status of OK. You should consult the API documentation. You've likely hit some sort of attempt or call quota